# how to get the words after colon symbol (:) using awk from the file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

For a shell script i need to get the password of the user from the file, the file is having a single line with the value for 4 parameters as below.

```
*:*:*:test:test
```

I want to get the 3rd and the 4th column alone excluding colon symbol (`:`) and pass it to an another variable.

Comment: Can you share what you'vre tried so far?

Comment: Do you need to use awk -- shell can do this very simply, and for multiple variables in one command.

Comment: This has worked "awk '{split($0,a,":"); print a[4],a[5]}'"

Comment: That extracts the values, but there is no syntax to assign them to two separate shell variables (you can assign them to an array as elements 0 and 1). Also, awk automatically separates fields: see the -F option and the syntax for field accesses.

Comment: If these are passwords, how would you handle a password that contains `:`?  Also, you say you want _two_ values in _one_ shell variable? What value should the variable contain _exactly_ given your example?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
VARIABLE=$(awk -F\: '{print $4}' input_file)
```

this will assign 4th parameter to variable named `VARIABLE`

Comment: Thanks Romeo for the suggestion, the edits are worked with the split. "awk '{split($0,a,":"); print a[4],a[5]}'"

Comment: @BalajiPanchatsaram, this is also possible, if you want tho variables print them with delimiter `:`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the use of `awk` is not specifically mandated, use Bash features to avoid using an external process:

```
IFS=':' read _ _ myCol3 myCol4 _ < myFile
```

The `_` is a valid variable name, but it is conventional to use it as a discard point. The last `_` gets any extra fields.

I note your example data has five values, not the 4 you state.

Edit: To set multiple array values extracted from a file (in this case, line 11 of my passwd file):

```
$ myArray+=( $( awk < /etc/passwd '-F:' 'NR == 11 { print $1, $3, $6; }' ) )
$ declare -p myArray
declare -a myArray=([0]="uucp" [1]="10" [2]="/var/spool/uucp")
$ echo "${myArray[1]}"
10
```

Comment: Yes Paul you are correct